# Add image to Titanium iOS module

Tags: ios, titanium

Seems like the official documents are out of date and none of its solution works for using image in Titanium iOS module.

According to http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Project, I should place images in assets directory and use relative path to get it in Objective C code. I did what it said but the image is null.

I located the actual application bundle and found out the image is in `modules/moduleid/xxx.png`, but the code just can't load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead following official guidelines like (which does not work apparently):

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"modules/%@/foo.png",[self moduleId]];
NSURL *url = [TiUtils toURL:path proxy:self];
UIImage *image = [TiUtils image:url proxy:self];
```

Do this:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"modules/%@/foo.png",[self moduleId]];    
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

In most cases, this code will be in custom views, which means the moduleId would be hard coded.